# Powermock removal and required code change

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I got rid of Powermock. How do I need to modify my setUp configuration to mock oDataQueryBuilder?

```
@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    modelSupplier = Mockito.spy(new OnPremiseOdataServiceImpl(objectMapper,
            resilienceConfiguration.cacheConfiguration(ResilienceConfiguration.CacheConfiguration.disabled())
            .circuitBreakerConfiguration(ResilienceConfiguration.CircuitBreakerConfiguration.disabled()),
            destinationResolver, DESTINATION, "/"));

    Mockito.doReturn(defaultHttpClient).when(destinationResolver).createHttpClient(Mockito.anyString(),
            Mockito.anyString());
    // Powermock.mockStatic(ODataQueryBuilder.class); // this line removed

    when(ODataQueryBuilder.withEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(oDataQueryBuilder); // this line cannot be done anymore due to static method

    when(oDataQueryBuilder.build()).thenReturn(oDataQuery);
    when(oDataQueryBuilder.param(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any())).thenReturn(oDataQueryBuilder);
    when(oDataQuery.execute(defaultHttpClient)).thenReturn(oDataQueryResult);
    when(oDataQueryResult.getStreamData()).thenReturn("{\"dummy\":{\"dummyField\":100}}");
}
```

One of my approach was to create an ODataQueryBuilderWrapper:
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQueryBuilder;

```
public interface ODataQueryBuilderWrapper {

    ODataQueryBuilder getWithEntity(String servicePath, String entity);
}
```

and:

```
import com.sap.cloud.sdk.odatav2.connectivity.ODataQueryBuilder;
import com.sap.rl.service.ODataQueryWrapper;

@Service
public class ODataQueryBuilderWrapperImpl implements ODataQueryWrapper {

    @Override
    public ODataQueryBuilder getWithEntity(String servicePath, String entity) {
        ODataQueryBuilder oDataQueryBuilder = ODataQueryBuilder.withEntity(servicePath, entity);
        return oDataQueryBuilder;
    }
}
```

then I can mock static method like this:

```
        when(oDataQueryWrapper.getWithEntity(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(oDataQueryBuilder);
```

But it didn't change anything at all! Any ideas?

Comment: You need to make `ODataQueryBuilder.withEntity` an instance message, and pass a mocked `ODataQueryBuilder` to your `ODataQueryBuilderWrapperImpl` constructor.